# ASP.Net MVC 3 Razor: Section Defined But Not Rendered Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following layout template:

```
<div id="columns" class="@View.LayoutClass">
    <div id="mainColWrap">
        <div id="mainCol">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
    @if (View.ShowLeftCol){
    <div id="leftCol">
        @RenderSection("LeftCol", required: false)
    </div>
    }
    @if (View.ShowRightCol){
    <div id="rightCol">
        @RenderSection("RightCol", required: false)
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

If View.ShowLeftCol or View.ShowRightCol are set to false, I get the following error:

---

The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "RightCol".

---

I am trying to have a single layout template instead of trying to dynamically select a template at runtime. Is there a way to ignore this error and continue rendering? Can anyone think of another way to implement that would allow me to dynamically show/hide columns with Razor?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Your layout template should *ALWAYS* include @RenderSection. Then it's up to your individual Razor views whether they want to implement the section or not.

Comment: I'm allowing users to create webpages where they can control whether or not to display the left/right columns for their pages (e.g. Webpage.Title, Webpage.MetaKeywords, Webpage.ShowLeftCol, Webpage.ShowRightCol, Webpage.MainContent). It all runs through the same controller and view. I suppose I could handle it in the View, but then I have to put things like my standard left nav in every view instead of the layout template and I also have to pull in my layout divs (<div id="leftCol">). Hopefully that makes sense. Let me know if you need more clarification as to why I want this in the layout.

Comment: What going on~I meet this problem too.
i've trid what Charles Gardner's suggestion,but it can't work.
So anyone have the way to solve it?

Comment: What I ultimately ended up doing was allowing users to select from different views which either did or did not define the needed sections. E.g. - WebPage3Col.cshtml, WebPage2ColLeft.cshtml, ... This also gave me the flexibility to create completely customized views for certain scenarios that fit outside the initial project scope.

Comment: Once again, I find myself annoyed at having to jump through hoops to get what should have been the default behaviour to work. If this actually needed to be handled at all - we're adults here, after all -  it could surely have been done better with some "option strict" flag to turn the all-sections-rendered validation on or off.   Does C# force me to use every variable I declare in every conditional branch of my code?  (Oh, did I say that out loud?  I really hope I haven't given anyone any ideas.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Was given a suggestion on the [ASP.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1626659.aspx) forums that works.

Essentially, if I define @section LeftCol in my view template but don't run any code that calls RenderSection in my layout, I get the error because it doesn't get called when View.ShowLeftCol is false. The suggestion was to add an else block and essentially throw away whatever contents are in the LeftCol section.

```
@if (View.ShowLeftCol)
{ 
<div id="leftCol"> 
    @RenderSection("LeftCol", false) 
</div> 
}
else
{
    WriteTo(new StringWriter(), RenderSection("LeftCol", false));
}
```

---

Based on the concern raised about memory I decided to test the following out as well. Indeed it also works.

```
@if (showLeft)
{
    <section id="leftcol">
        <div class="pad">
            @RenderSection("LeftColumn", false)
        </div>
    </section>
}
else
{
    WriteTo(TextWriter.Null, RenderSection("LeftColumn", false));
}
```

Also, at the top of my page, this is my new logic for showLeft/showRight:

```
bool showLeft = IsSectionDefined("LeftColumn");
bool showRight = IsSectionDefined("RightColumn");
bool? hideLeft  = (bool?)ViewBag.HideLeft;
bool? hideRight = (bool?)ViewBag.HideRight;
if (hideLeft.HasValue && hideLeft.Value == true) { showLeft = false; }
if (hideRight.HasValue && hideRight.Value == true) { showRight = false; }
```

Someone else said it didn't work for them, but it worked like a charm for me.

Comment: I'm handling this differently now. In the database I allow the users to supply a view name in order to override my default views. I still have one master layout, but I make use of the IsSectionDefined() function to determine whether or not the view defines a left and/or right column section and the subsequent columns should be output in the layout.

Comment: This doesn't even work for me. I had to use reflection and set a _renderedSections HashSet<string> that is on a parent class of WebView. By adding a string with the section name, I tricked it into thinking the section was rendered. Very hacky and ugly but it worked.

Comment: While passing a new StringWriter instance in will work, it's going to create extra memory pressure because it has a finalizer and Dispose() won't be called; a better choice would be to use TextWriter.Null.

Comment: Worked like a charm in MVC 4!

Comment: This answer was a life saver - trying to push web code to production and this item provided the fix.

Answer (score 2):

```
@using System.Reflection;
@{
    HashSet<string> renderedSections = typeof(WebPageBase).GetField("_renderedSections", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField).GetValue(this) as HashSet<string>;
}
```

Then add to that hash set whatever section name you want to pretend to have rendered.

Comment: That's pretty neat! Surprised this hasn't got more upvotes since it bypasses the rendering completely, unlike the other solutions which just discard the rendered content.

Comment: Wish MSFT would expose this as a method or public field :)

Comment: Well they've had 7 years to think about it so I wouldn't hold your breath! :-/

Comment: this solution should fix my problem but `renderedSections.Add("MySection")` didn't work, still got the error

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (View.ShowLeftCol)
{ 
<div id="leftCol"> 
    @RenderSection("LeftCol", false) 
</div> 
}
else{  <!-- @RenderSection("LeftCol", false) -->  }
```

easier way!!

Comment: That will render the section anyway, only it'll be commented out. Besides the total lack of efficiency, what if there's sensitive/security trimmed information in the section?

Comment: I agree Sandor.. That was just a way... I've another shortcut which doesn't renders anything at all ---- if(condition){@RenderSection("sectionName").ToString().Remove(0)}