# Is it possible to make Razor sections optional?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

If I have a page with:

```
<body>
    @section SomeStuff {
        <span>This is a section I just addered</span>
    }

</body>
```

Is it possible for the layout to *not* render this section, or is that contrary to how this should work conceptually. Seems like it would be useful to be able to not render certain sections on a page (unless I'm thinking about this incorrectly).

**Edit:**

Including the error message may be helpful, when I put a section into the *main* page, the *layout* page fails with: `The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "/Views/Layouts/_Layout1.cshtml": "SomeStuff".` As if it's forcing me to render every section on the page or something.

In otherwords, in Layout.cshtml, I *don't* call @RenderSection, but in Index.html I have a section called `SomeStuff` defined. Is that legal? Seems like it's forcing me to render all sections in the page, but that seems like sections should be optional, no?

Comment: You mean like an `if` statement?

Comment: I love addering things too

Comment: @daveL - great minds think alike.

Comment: Old question, but see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4270739/3692256

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can specify if a section is required.

```
@RenderSection("SomeStuff", required: false)
```

if you don't render it out in a view, it shouldn't error then, noted here

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer? It deals with another question! It's the other way around: I define a section in the view, then I don't use it in the layout - can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

You can set a section to be optional by setting the required parameter to false. If you'd like to include some optional wrapper HTML around your section then you can also use the *IsSectionDefined* method.

```
@if(IsSectionDefined("SideBar"))
{
    <div class="sidebar">
        @RenderSection("SideBar", required: false)
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For a certain layout not to render certain section you need to have  something like this is your layout.cshtml

```
@RenderSection("Somestuff", required:false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
  @if (condition) {
     @RenderSection("SomeStuff")
  }
```

Or just use a `conditional statement` directly rather than `@RenderSection`:

```
 @if (yourCondition) {
    <span>This is a section I just addered</span>
 }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but when I put the section into the *main* page, the *layout* page fails because it does not call `@RenderSection("SomeStuff")`. It seems like rendering sections ought to be optional, but it isn't behaving like it is.

Comment: I get `The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "/Views/Layouts/_Layout1.cshtml": "SomeStuff".` Sounds like it's forcing me to render the section.

Comment: @sircodesalot - I believe that layout wants you to include @RenderSection("SomeStuff") ... you could put your condition in the layout and call it there (like I have shown you).... or just use `@if (yourCondition) { }` in the page directly (no section needed) which does not involve the `layout` page.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue when I was trying to dynamically inject code into an inline script, I solved it via:

```
@if (someCondition)
    {
        @Html.Raw(@"
              Your stuff here
        ");
    }
```