# Can I choose not to render a certain section in the layout page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC layout page that is used by all the views in my application. Each of these views defines a "PanelRight" section, that is rendered in the layout page. However, now I would like to replace that section with some other markup. I thought it'd be as easy as commenting out the `RenderSection` instruction and adding my new markup, but I keep getting an exception ("The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page").

I understand what the exception means; I only want to know how to get rid of it. Id est, can I NOT render a certain section that is defined in the views? Because I'd much rather not go through all of them and removing the section.

**EDIT**

I'll try to be more clear.

Suppose this is my layout page:

```
<html>
    <head> <!-- HEAD STUFF --> </head>
    <body>
        @RenderSection("RightPanel", false)
        @RenderBody()
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is one of my *many* views:

```
@section RightPanel {
    <div>This is the markup of the section</div>
}

<div>This is the body of my view</div>
```

Now I decide that, rather than having a RightPanel section that can be customized by each view, I want to have a fixed content instead. So I "remove" the section and replace it with the markup I want to use - straight into the layout (actually it will be in another partial, but *not in a section*, that's the point).

Of course, I don't want to go through all of my *many* views to delete the `@section RightPanel { }`. I just want the layout page to *ignore* the section. To make a comparison, it's like I defined a class with a `DoFancyStuff()` method, and then in the client code I never call that method. Not a problem there, so I see no reason why it would be here.

To recap: the view defines a section, the layout doesn't intend to render it. This results in an error. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @CodeCaster, yes, it is a duplicate of that question, but there is no actual answer to that question. Neither I nor the other OP asked how to make it so that not all of the layout's sections had to be implemented in the view - and the answers addressed this. Instead, we are asking if I can HAVE a section in the view but NOT USE IT in the layout.

So yes, it's an answer that was already asked, but it's not been answered yet, and it's wrong that there is an accepted answer there.

Comment: The answer is _"a section defined as non-optional (default) **must** be rendered"_. "No, you can't" is a valid answer.

Comment: The only reference to what you mention is this sentence in the accepted answer: "if you don't render it out in a view, it shouldn't error then". And this is apparently wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I (just like @Chris) misunderstood your question. A section is defined only once, is it that hard to comment out the (CS)HTML in the actual `@section` as defined in your layout? It would perhaps help if you'd show some (pseudo)code of what your section and the calling code look like, and what you want it to do.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @CodeCaster, this would not be lighter than removing (commenting) the section. If I have 100 views using that layout (some of them, say 70, define the section, the other 30 don't), I'd rather comment ONE `RenderSection` in the layout than comment SEVENTY section definitions.

Comment: Then see [ASP.Net MVC 3 Razor: Section Defined But Not Rendered Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262045/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-section-defined-but-not-rendered-error): you render the section to `TextWriter.Null`, esentially rendering the section into a black hole.

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster, that is indeed a good answer. I'll probably go with the simpler suggestion by Chris Pratt, but this is fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot have a section in your view that your layout does not implement. This will result in a runtime error, and there's no way around that. The reason everyone is telling you how to implement optional sections is because the layout must implement any section any view might want to use, but, by making it optional, you can allow some views to use some sections while other views use other sections.

> So, if I want to "comment out" a RenderSection, if just for a test, do I really have to go through all views and remove that section definition?

Technically, yes. Although you could simply wrap the section in regular HTML comments `<!-- -->`, so while it's rendered, it's rendered as an HTML comment instead of actual DOM elements. Also, with layout inheritance, you can sort of short circuit the views' sections by defining an empty section. For example:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@RenderSection("Foo")
```

**_SubLayout.cshtml**

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }

@section Foo {}
```

**SomeView.cshtml**

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SubLayout.cshtml"; }

@section Foo
{
    <!-- stuff here --> 
}
```

The section `Foo` would be empty because the sub-layout implements `Foo` but doesn't also call `@RenderSection("Foo")` itself, so there's no opportunity for a view using it as a layout to alter that section. That won't really help you now much, but it's good to know for future reference.

I suppose you could create a new layout with a different name and move the stuff from your current layout there while making your current layout inherit from the new layout. That would allow you to implement this without having to update all your layout references in your views. However, it will likely be easier to just to use HTML comments to comment out your section in your layout for testing purposes.

**UPDATE**

Just one more thing. Now that I'm thinking about it, the layout inheritance approach I suggested as one potential method, may actually not work. It occurred to me that you may still get an error because the sub-layout doesn't call `@RenderSection`. It all depends on whether the initial call in the main layout is enough to satisfy. HTML comments are definitely the safest and easiest approach.

**UPDATE BY OP**

Accepted answer:

**you could simply wrap the section in regular HTML comments `<!-- -->`, so while it's rendered, it's rendered as an HTML comment instead of actual DOM elements.**

Comment: So, if I want to "comment out" a RenderSection, if just for a test, do I really have to go through all views and remove that section definition? :-(

Comment: The HTML comment suggestion may in fact work. I'll try that.