# Un-needed RenderSection in Razor MVC

Tags: c#, razor

I have a hierarchy of nested LayoutFiles, and I need the ability, in the very top layout, to ignore 'Sections' of code that I don't need for the print view.

The print view is intended to be a cut down version of the normal view, sidebar removed, javascript removed, all css removed etc etc.

```
@if (Model.IsPrint)
{
     @* specifically NO 'headerscripts' section *@
}
else
{
     @RenderSection("HeaderScripts", false)
}
```

but doing that gives me this sort of error when attempting to print:

```
The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/Layout/_MasterLayout.cshtml": "HeaderScripts; FooterScripts".
```

I know I could be using...

```
 IsSectionDefined("HeaderScripts")
```

.. for example, but that would require changing the other layouts calling this layout, and I'd prefer keeping all the logic in this layout.

Also, I don't want to Render those sections inside a comment, I know that would work too but it's far too messy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you find your answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262045/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-section-defined-but-not-rendered-error). But it seems, you **have** to call RenderSection(), even if you discard the content..

Comment: any good suggestion how to "discard" the content without a comment?

Comment: In the question I linked they end up using `WriteTo(TextWriter.Null, RenderSection("xyz", false));`

Comment: @churill awesome, that does actually look ok, at least that way it doesn't render non-visual html in the browser.

Comment: @churill awesome code doesn't work, output of RenderSection is 'null' so cant be parsed to 'WriteTo' :-(

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define the section as optional, in the layout, like this:

`@RenderSection("HeaderScripts", required: false)`

Comment: the relationship is the other way, what you've got says the view files using the layout can optionally use that section, whereas I'm using a section that may or may not be defined. All my sections are already optional